# Как менять значение переменной angular при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: angular, angular4, angular8, angular10

Нужно менять значение при нажатии на кнопку
Есть переменная orderBy: string;
При нажатии на кнопку я вызываю функцию

```
sortByID(){
 
    this.sortBy = "idDesc";
    
  }
```

Сейчас у нее значение idDesc, а я хочу что б при повторном нажатии ее значение поменялось на idAsc
Вот где вызываю функцию

```
<img src="../../../../assets/sort.png" mat-button (click)="sortByID()"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
sortByID() { 
    this.sortBy = this.sortBy.localeCompare('idDesc') === 0? 'idAsc' : 'idDesc';    
}
```

[localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)

В принципе, можно и по-простому:

```
this.sortBy = this.sortBy === 'idDesc'? 'idAsc' : 'idDesc';
```

Comment: выдает ошибку ```ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'localeCompare' of undefined```

Comment: пробую вот так ```this.sortBy = "idAsc" ? "idDesc" : "idAsc";``` оно работает только в одну сторону,то есть на idDesc меняет , а на idAsc уже нет. Не подскажите в чем проблема?

Comment: @Dmitriy имя свойства sortId, или orderId? А то в вопросе, и видимо в коде мне кажется перепутано

Comment: имя переменной sortBy или что вы имеете ввиду

Comment: А да я перепутал в вопросе

Comment: @Dmitriy и код проверьте, тут все элементарно - должно работать как часы